# How to add breakline in a for loop in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a loop that returns error messages, is there a way to add a break line `<br />` after each message? Or do I need to somehow do this in the page? It works correctly but isn't formatted very nicely.

```
for (int i = 0; i < funcRespCust.ResponseInfoItems.Count(); i++)
{
    TempData["StatusMessage"] = TempData["StatusMessage"] + funcRespCust.ResponseInfoItems[i].Message + " ";
}
```

The code on the page that displays the errors is as below.

```
@if (@TempData["StatusMessage"].ToString() != "allok")
{
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <i class="fa fa-frown-o"></i>
    <strong>@TempData["StatusMessage"].ToString()</strong>
</div>
}
```

I tried putting the break line at the end of the message after the space as below and obviously this just writes out the `<br />` as part of the error message.

```
funcRespCust.ResponseInfoItems[i].Message + " <br />";
```

I imagine there's a pretty simple solution to insert the HTML somehow that I can't seem to find...

Thanks

**UPDATE:** Is there a reason why this is frowned upon? Seems like the simplest solution and it does work.

```
<strong>@Html.Raw(TempData["StatusMessage"].ToString())</strong>
```

Comment: Your can use `@Html.Raw()` to format it with the line break (or use `Environment.NewLine` in the controller and put the output in an element styled with `white-space: pre;`

Comment: `<strong>@TempData["StatusMessage"].ToString()<br/></strong>` is perfectly acceptable and I would say the preferred solution

Comment: @SimonGates Unfortunately that just adds a single <br/> after all the error messages, not between each of them.

Comment: Ah! of course it does - time for some coffee! Stephen's Environment.NewLine  is a good solution to save you from having to render HTML.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Regarding your update: **Separation of concerns**. Generally you want to separate the data from the markup; the controller decides *what* is to be displayed and the view decides *how*.  By adding a `<br/>` into your data, you dictate how it will be displayed on the view rather than letting the view handle it.  Suppose your users review the UI and say - these errors would be better with bullet points - that's a simple change in the UI if you'd used a list.

Comment: @freedomn-m Understood, thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why this is frowned upon?  To name one, you have now potentially given a hacker an attack vector for XSS attacks, you may currently know that this is OK because it doesn't render any user input, but future you and future dev's will have to remember this and that's the problem people forget and people can make incorrect assumptions. That's why I like Stpehen's `Evironment.NewLine` solution

Comment: @SimonGates Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not do it properly, by returning a list of errors/strings. And display them as you like, rather than controlling how they are going to be consumed from backemd.

```
TempData["StatusMessage"] = new List<string>(); //should be a complex object
for (int i = 0; i < funcRespCust.ResponseInfoItems.Count(); i++)
{
    TempData["StatusMessage"].Add(funcRespCust.ResponseInfoItems[i].Message);
}

@if (@TempData["StatusMessage"].Any())
{
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <i class="fa fa-frown-o"></i>
<strong>
//loop declaration
{
    @TempData["StatusMessage"][i].ToString() + "<br />
}

</strong>
</div>
}
```

P.S. my example might need syntax correction.

Comment: my upv, I completely misunderstood the question!

Answer (score 0):

Use **@Html.Raw:**

It will **render your html** which you have store in object

```
@Html.Raw(COnvert.ToString(TempData["StatusMessage"]))
```

**Controller Code:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
        TempData["StatusMessage"] = "Sandip";
        TempData["StatusMessage"] += "<br/>";
        TempData["StatusMessage"] += "Patel";
        return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.Raw(Convert.ToString(TempData["StatusMessage"]))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I upvoted it because it *is* the correct answer to a badly composed question